# Querystring inside Querystring

Tags: encoding, hyperlink

I have a problem on my webpage with an querystring I have to pass inside a querystring.

The main querystring is a cookie checker. And inside this I need to pass a second URL that contain also a querystring with &. The second querystring is now broken after website is parsed:

http://www.myurl.com/check_affiliate_cookie_exist.jsp?contractId=3241248&referrer=*&foundString=linkok&notFoundString=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=WZ7CHZVKKLNQW"

When I now click on the second link, it is broken at & and the second part of this "sub querystring" is broken.

Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: Use PHP's `urlencode()` to encode characters like `&` to be passed in the url. Then call `urldecode()` to retrieve the original url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape, you can use js for example

```
var url = mainUrl + encodeURIComponent(secondUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **rawurlencode** if you're using PHP. You will then need to decode the URL using **rawurldecode**. If you're not using PHP, then check for equivalent functions in your scripting language.

Hope this helps!